# Warning for anonymous union assignment in C

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, unions, discriminated-union

I'm building a small demonstration of a stack in C. As C has no exceptions, I'm trying out the result pattern (similar to `Result<>` in Swift 5) to deal with errors in creation, push, and pop.

I've created a header file that includes an error enum:

```
typedef enum {
  no_error,
  illegal_stack_capacity,
  out_of_memory,
  stack_element_too_large,
  stack_full,
  stack_empty
} stack_error;
```

a struct for the stack itself (I am using a stack of strings for concreteness, because at this point I am simply experimenting:

```
typedef struct {
    char** data;     // array of strings, capacity set on create()
    int capacity;    // have to store this separately!
    int top;         // index of next slot to fill, also the size
} stack;
```

and now to capture errors, I thought I would build a little struct that has an error part and a success part. As I am experimenting, I tried to have the error part do double duty as both a discriminated union tag as well as capture the error. This may be a hack, but it leads to (what I think is maybe) an interesting question.

```
typedef struct {
    stack_error error;
    union {
        stack* stack;    // because create() returns a stack
        char* value;     // because pop() returns a string
    };
} result;
```

For reference (and sorry for the clutter), I have these functions:

```
result create(int capacity);
int size(const stack* s);
bool is_empty(const stack* s);
bool is_full(const stack* s);
stack_error push(stack* s, char* item);
result pop(stack* s);
void destroy(stack** s);
```

Now the question is that every time I build a `result` object, the C *compiler* seems to always assume the anonymous union component of my `result` struct is supposed to be a `stack*`. When I write, in my `create` function

```
return (result){no_error, s};
```

the compiler is fine with it, but when I write this in my `pop` function:

```
return (result){no_error, popped_value};
```

the compiler gives me a warning:

```
boundedstack.c:57:31: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing
  'stack *' with an expression of type 'char *'
  [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
return (result){no_error, popped_value};
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I know I can get around this by (1) making the union not be anonymous or (2) creating separate types for `stack_result` (for create) and `string_result` (for pop), and maybe I **should** do that, but I am intrigued by this warning was wondering if any C language experts would know if anything in the language dictates that kind of warning, or if the warning was simply a decision by the compiler implementers to say "hey well I am just going to assume the proper type for the union is the first one I see". The code works just fine, but it *seems* to me the compiler could have done a better job. Or could it have? *Could* the compiler have done a better job? Or would it be too expensive of a check in the compiler?

(I really don't want to suppress warnings, as that is bad practice. Am I wrong to have tried the anonymous union?)

Comment: You could also do `return (result){.error=no_error, .value=popped_value};`

Comment: Oh that's beautiful I did not think of it. If you covert to an answer, I'm happy to accept (though I do wonder about why the compiler writers seemed to have shortcutted their warning message)

Comment: I'm thinking now maybe the compiler writers had the expectation that struct literals _should_ include the field names and that gave them license to simplify the error message, but maybe deep in the C language definition there is an expectation that if the field names are omitted the first union element is assumed? Good question for language lawyers, I think (but could be wrong)

Comment: I also think it's a good question, but unfortunately I only know the workaround :)

Comment: It does point me in a good direction to dive into the ISO standard; I had not thought that the designators would matter here but they might

Comment: `create` never returns a string and `pop` never returns a stack. They are two different types of result and each deserves a C type of its own. No reason to use a union here IMHO. There's nothing wrong with such a union in principle, just not in this case.

Comment: Both compound literals and designated initializers were introduced in C99.  Prior to that, you could indeed only initialize the first element of a union.  Your code would have been written with a temporary object instead, and explicit assignment: `result r; r.error = no_error; r.value = v; return r;`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I will ultimately go with `string_result` and `stack_result` as you are absolutely right.

Comment: Section 6.7.9 (Initialization) paragraph 17 (emphasis added): "Each brace-enclosed initializer list has an associated current object. **When no designations are present**, subobjects of the current object are initialized in order according to the type of the current object: array elements in increasing subscript order, structure members in declaration order, and **the first named member of a union**."

Comment: Ahhhhhhh THERE IT IS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to get around the error is to use designated initialization:

```
return (result){.error=no_error, .value=popped_value};
```